# Calculating volume of building in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: 3d-analyst, arcgis-pro

I want to calculate the volume of buildings in arcgis. 
The data consists of 3D multipatches (shapefile).

One building consists of different multipolygons. I can calculate the volume of the single multipolygons with the built-in functions of the 3D-Analyst (minimum bounding volume, convex hull).

The problem is that one building is composed of several multipolygons that aren't related to the building via an ID.

Therefore I need to do a spatial match between the different polygons of a building.

Any suggestions of how to do that using ArcGIS Pro?

I was not able to execute 3Dunion of the 3D analyst).